# How would a stone age human adult adapt to our society

Tags: stoneage

Suppose we find a frozen adult human from the stone age that somehow can be reanimated to a healthy state.

How would he react and adapt? He would probably first be panicked and think he is in hell or paradise. However do you think that over the long run it would be possible to communicate with him? Make him understand that he is in the future? Would he be able to understand that electricity or planes are not magic?

Comment: How many people nowadays do understand what electricity is or how planes stay in the sky?

Comment: Antropologists and sociologists have been wondering about this for decades. Well.. Not specifically about frozen stone age humans, but rather about how humans adapt to completely novel technologies, societies, cultures and environments. The fact of the matter is they (and by extension we) still don't really know. And so really your tread is  ultimately opinion-based (and IMHO too broad, as it includes 5 questions, each of which could warrent entire scholarly papers).

Comment: I would be worried about their primitive immune system, one cough means extinction....

Comment: Putting a close vote on this because it fails the Write A Book test: you can write an entire book as the answer here and that makes it much too broad for Worldbuilding SE. Also note that a) hell and heaven are **christian** concepts, i.e. they came about thousands of years after the stone age and b) when you start answering the question yourself, then that is a thread on which you should pull long and hard before asking a question, because then you are obviously not stuck.

Comment: I remember reading about the movie "The Gods Must Be Crazy" that their main actor was something like that (not exactly a hunter-gatherer tribesman as portrayed in the movie, but close). They filmed his natural reaction to all the stuff he had never experienced before (a plane, a bottle, a bicycle, a car, etc.) The reaction was nothing like shock or panic, it was more like "oh, a weird bird... a weird man... a weird animal..." Something like a person who has never seen gods or magic, but truly believes they exist would react on actually seeing them for the first time.

Comment: @MichaelK "hell and heaven are christian concepts" - not really, much earlier cultures had some concept of afterlife where you're either rewarded or punished.

Comment: @Headcrab Point taken.

Comment: The "stone age" was 3.4 million years long, come back with a specific point of adaptation and a time period that actually gives us something to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Would we be able to establish communication? That depends on whether or not your Stone Age adult knows language. Scholars seem to agree that language developped some time during the Stone Age (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language#Origin), but that covers 3.4 million years and several different species of the genus Homo.

So you'd need to specify that a bit more.

If this person has language abilities, then we can probably establish communication and begin to teach this person, just like we teach children.

The actual result is hard to predict, since it would depend on the individual and her ability to learn and adapt. Becoming a normal member of society would probably be out of the question, especially since she would probably be world famous.